# QGIS: Remove "Point" text from geom_to_wkt() function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm still learning QGIS, so this could be a rookie question.  I've been able to create a Label with the co-ordinates of my Layout's centre point in UTM (Map is in a different CRS)

```
[%  geom_to_wkt(transform(map_get(item_variables('map_1'), 'map_extent_center'), 'EPSG:3857',  'EPSG:32755'),0) %]
```

But the result has the text "Point" in front of it: `Point(123..,456..)` I'd assume that's because it is a 'point' object/value that's being returned. How can I show just the two numerical values? Or is there another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It says `POINT` because that is what the WKT (Well Known Text) representation requires it to do. If you want the X and Y values of the point then you want to use the [`x()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsPoint.html#qgis.core.QgsPoint.x) and [`y()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsPoint.html#qgis.core.QgsPoint.y) methods of the Geometry object.

Comment: Thank you. Working backwards I deduced the 'geometry' object in my example is created by `transform(map_get(item_variables('map_1'), 'map_extent_center'), 'EPSG:3857',  'EPSG:32755')`, After more work, I was able to neaten it all up into:
 `[%'Centre: ' || round(x(transform(map_get(item_variables('map_1'), 'map_extent_center'), 'EPSG:3857',  'EPSG:32755'))) || ', ' || round(y(transform(map_get(item_variables('map_1'), 'map_extent_center'), 'EPSG:3857',  'EPSG:32755')))%]`   Thanks again!